# SQlite EntityframeworkCore Linq query on column not working: InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

###### The Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(k => (GroupAddress)k.Address == __notification_Destination_0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

###### The source code which leads to the aforementioned exception

```cs
// works
var x = await dbContext.AddressConfigurations.SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == 1);

// fails with the exception below
// Single() or First() makes no difference regarding the exception. Should be Single() but I have no unique constraint so far.
var y = await dbContext.AddressConfigurations.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Address == notification.Destination);
```

###### The database model

```
public class AddressConfiguration
{
    public AddressConfiguration(string address, string dataType)
    {
        Address = address;
        DataType = dataType;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string DataType { get; set; }

    public string? Location { get; set; }
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing here? Do I need to define an index for that column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the exception specifying cast to `GroupAddress` it seems that `notification.Destination` is a `GroupAddress` and there is implicit cast from `string` to it. Comparison of two arbitrary custom types can't be translated by EF AFAIK, so you need to convert `notification.Destination` to `string`. Depending on `GroupAddress` implementation you can try just an explicit cast (if it is implemented):

```cs
var y = await dbContext.AddressConfigurations
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Address == (string)notification.Destination);
```

Or `ToString()`:

```cs
var y = await dbContext.AddressConfigurations
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Address == notification.Destination.ToString());
```

Or you will need to construct a valid searchable string manually:

```cs
var y = await dbContext.AddressConfigurations
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Address == notification.Destination.SomeProp + " " + notification.Destination.SomeOtherProp);
```