# C# Implicit conversion of "someValue" from 'string' to 'StringValues' in Rider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jetbrains-rider

Working with ASP.Net Core in Rider (learning it) and trying to set the Response headers.
The headers work great, no problems. But in the Rider it adds some information (as on the image below) with the tip:

> Implicit conversion of "someValue" from 'string' to 'StringValues'

[image]

What does this message mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# has a mechanism for user to define an implicit conversion from one type to another i.e. usually (since types are validated by the compiler) given two unrelated user-defined types `T1` and `T2` the following `T1 x = new T2();` will result in compiler error, but with implicit conversion defined compiler will use it and this code will work. See more in [user-defined explicit and implicit conversion operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) doc.

`context.Response.Headers` is a [`IHeaderDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iheaderdictionary?view=aspnetcore-7.0) which has an [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/) property [of type `StringValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iheaderdictionary.item?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-iheaderdictionary-item(system-string)) which has an implicit conversion from `string`. The implicit conversion is [defined like this](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives/StringValues.cs,51):

```cs
public static implicit operator StringValues(string? value)
{
     return new StringValues(value);
}
```

Implicit conversions sometimes can be tricky ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75324314/2501279)) so it seems that Rider team decided that it worth to notify user in some way when one is happening.

Comment: Thank you! I need to dig deeper into the CSharp. :)

Comment: @Arsenii was glad to help! Yes, C# has quite a lot of features =)